# How can I calculate $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_{(3)})$? And $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, schemes

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ be the localization (in $\mathbb{Z}$) of the ideal generated by $3$. So I have to put in $\mathbb{Z}$ all the inverses of the complement of $(3)$. How can I calculate $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_{(3)})$? And $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_3)$? Where in the last situation I do the localization in the element $3$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ then?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}$ is dimension $1$, and the prime ideals of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_{(3)})$ correspond to the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ sitting below $(3)$.

Comment: The same analysis works, for the other case, right? Namely, the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ correspond to the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ not intersecting $\{1,3,\ldots\}$. Well, since such an ideal is prime and can't contain $1$, it's evident that not intersecting $\{1,3,\ldots\}$ is the same as not containing $3$. So, the primes are precisely $p\mathbb{Z}_3$ where $p\ne 3$.

Comment: The general results are: 1) if $R$ is a commutative ring and $\frak p$ its prime ideal, then the prime ideal of the localization $R_{\frak p}$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ that are contained in $\frak p$. 2) if $s$ is a non-zero divisor of $R$ and $R_{s}$ is the localizationg w.r.t the multiplicative set of non-negative powers of $s$, then the prime ideals of $R_{s}$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ that do not have $s$ as an element. Can you apply these here?

Comment: By the way, this should be clear if you understand geometrically what localizing at these two sets does.

Comment: @Jyrki: This is probably an answer, more than a comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: 2) holds also for zero-divisors.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I don't know exactly what is the geometric interpretation of the localization in an element of the ring. For example if I localize $\mathbb{C}[x]$ in $x$ I find $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$... what's mean?

Comment: @ArthurStuart Right, and so geometrically you've shown that the closed points of $\mathbb{C}[x]_x$ are in correspondence with $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and since $\mathbb{C}[x]_x$ is dimension 1, you only have closed points and $(0)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis But what is in general, the geometric interpretation?